# Cannot Install Accomplishments

Tags: accomplishments

I have tried to install Ubuntu Accomplishments on my clean 12.10 install.

Following the installation instructions as outlined [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/Installing)
After entering the final command

`sudo apt-get install accomplishments-daemon accomplishments-viewer ubuntu-community-accomplishments ubuntu-desktop-accomplishments accomplishments-lens`

I get the following unable to locate package

`Reading package lists... Done`

`Building dependency tree`

`Reading state information... Done`

`E: Unable to locate package accomplishments-lens`

I checked Software sources and the ppa: was successfully added and no problems were shown after `sudo apt-get update`

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Add accomplishment repository again and retry:)

Comment: I think it would be great if you reported a bug against accomplishments system abou this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed accomplishments 3 months ago. Yesterday when i tried to update my Ubuntu there was an error in accomplishments-lens that stopped me from using `apt-get update` so I removed it from my system.

since ypu have the same problem (I thought I am the only one who has it). May be the `accomplishments-lens package` has been removed from the repository ?

Now if you really want to install accomplishment run the command again but without

`accomplishments-lens`

Comment: Note: The accomplishments-lens package is optional, it provides integration with dash, but it is not needed to use the rest of accomplishments system.